# refresh page once cookie has been set via javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies, refresh

I have ran into an issue while trying to refresh a page in JavaScript once a cookie has been set.

I basically set a cookie once a check box has been checked. I then refresh the page, and remove the cookie or expire it in my case. But for some reason the page just keeps refreshing. Here is my code:

```
document.cookie="accept=1";
var accept = getCookie("accept"); 

if (accept =="1") {
    document.cookie = "accept=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC";
    window.location.reload();
}
```

Are there any issues with the above?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (accept =="1") {
    document.cookie = "accept=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC";
    window.location.reload();
}
```

this will refresh the page very time as you have set the cookie just before it, i dont see why you would want to refresh the page anyway? If you have content based on the cookie it is available when you set the cookie?

Comment: Doesn't expiring the cookie remove it?